# Best option to interface a Xamarin.Forms app with Azure SQL Server

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to study a use case where I have a Xamarin.Forms application which interfaces with the Azure platform; in particular, with an SQL Database.

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WebServices/TodoAzure/TodoAzure/TodoItemManager.cs) for the Xamarin part, and created a Web App and a SQL Database (with a SQL Server) for the Azure part, like shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started).

So I created a table in the database and modified the .NET backend of the guide 
replacing the TodoItem class with the new class that represents my table.

After the deployment, nothing seemed to be changed.

The Xamarin code, by the way, with the class `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient`, seems to be calling a REST API; the connection to the web app is successful, but there's an error on a request like this:

`Invalid sync operation: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/Address?$filter=not(complete)', Version: 2.0, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: 3d018c77-7c83-4635-9592-31cdbbb4c21a
  Accept: application/json
  User-Agent: ZUMO/4.1
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X86; version=4.1.1.0)
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/4.1 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X86; version=4.1.1.0)
  ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
  Accept-Encoding: gzip
}`

Accessing `https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/tables/Address` from a Web browser, in fact, returns an error.

Have you ever experienced something like this? I cannot find any REST service in Azure. The MobileServiceClient seems very good, it provides a very good level of abstraction, so I would prefer something like this than a custom REST client.

Thank you.

Comment: And `myapp` in the url is what you called your app in the Azure Portal?

Comment: It's an example in this case, but yes, the request calls the correct app url.

Comment: Are you able to test it on Postman successfully?